# SSIS execution error in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to Execute a dtsx file in Visual Studio 2012.  I've created an Integration Services Solution?Project, and added the dtsx file to it, however, when I right-click and select Execute I get the following error -

### ****TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
 (Application Import)****

---

Also, outside of VS, when selecting the dtsx file in my windows Explorer, it does not give me the option to Open the file with VS.  And when I try to I get the following error

"The program you have selected cannot be associated with this file type.  Please choose another program."

I realize more details may be necessary, please feel free to ask for further information.

Comment: How was the `.dtsx` created?

Comment: Yep, sounds like you're trying to import an invalid .dtsx.

Comment: I have not manually operated on the dtsx file.  It does mention it is corrupted.  I copied the file from my SQL Manager database to my desktop (as per instructions on another site) and added it to my VS project.  Any other/better way I could open the file to be executed?